# Tunelling And How to Tunnel

Tags: sockets, networking, tunnel, data-protection

I'm connected to a network that sends and receives a bunch of data packets, but these packets are visible to others (can be sniffed) so I want to tunnel them. I don't know how! I know about socket programming, proxies, vpns, all of the protocols like PPTP, SSH, SSL, TLS, etc. I'm looking for the actual CODE that **takes the packages before they're sent**,**sends them by tunneling (encapsulating the data)**
How can I do this?
Any information regarding this subject or how to tunnel is appreciated!

Comment: You want code but are providing no system requirements. Linux or windows, any specific language?

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh and socks proxy:

```
ssh -D 5000 remotehost.com
```

Then, while your SSH session is alive, you can configure your local apps (such as your web browser) to use this connection as an encrypted tunnel.  Just configure them use use localhost:5000 as the socks proxy server, and you're good to go.  Note that the packets will only be encrypted between your client and the remote ssh server - once they leave the server, they will be in whatever form they usually are.

If you are on windows, you can do with with putty.